# Google Maps API v3: Why does the label of MakerWithLabel change only when I zoom?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a `MarkerWithLabel` with a label that I want to change periodically. 
So I do this:

```
 myMark.labelContent = "<some new text>";
```

When the update is done, both the marker and the label move as they should, the maker changes icon as it should, but the content of the label is not updated. However, when I zoom in/out with the mouse wheel, the label is finally updated.

Is this normal, or I am doing something stupid? Sounds like a bug...

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. When you set the `labelContent`-property in this way the MarkerWithLabel-instance does not recognize that this property has been changed, nothing will happen until the marker must be redrawn(e.g. when you zoom) and the property will be accessed again.

You must use the setter-method of the `google.maps.MVCObject`( a MarkerWithLabel is an instance of MVCObject), then the instance will be notified that the property has changed:

```
myMark.set('labelContent','some new text');
```